# SQL Query - Remove Commas Within Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am running a SQL query on some customer data. Within my Select statement I ideally need to remove all commas.(I am not looking to update my source tables.)

Not certain how to do this on all fields and all columns, so any help or insight would be much appreciated.

If you need any additional information, please let me know.

Thank you,

Allison

Comment: The SQL statement you have now, sample data, current output, and what you are expecting (from the updated query).

Comment: Your question is very confusing, could you edit with more details?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you need to remove the commas in any of your data (in columns)
and replacing the comma by a space

```
Select Replace(ColA,',',' ') as ColA, Replace(ColB,',',' ') as ColB ...
From
```